# Insert locale check into setter

Tags: java

I'm using this Java code to set Locale:

```
wpfRequest.setTransactionId(uniqueId).setUsage("TICKETS")
    .setCurrency(Currency.EUR.getCurrency()).setAmount(new PriceRangeUtil().getPrice()).setCustomerEmail(email);

Locale requestLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
String language = requestLocale.getLanguage();
if ("en".equals(language)){
   wpfRequest.setLanguage(com.emerchantpay.gateway.api.constants.Locales.EN);
}
if ("bg".equals(language)){
   wpfRequest.setLanguage(com.emerchantpay.gateway.api.constants.Locales.BG);
}
```

How to implement the locale check logic into `setLanguage(.....)` setter?
Where [this](https://github.com/GenesisGateway/genesis_java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/emerchantpay/gateway/api/constants/Locales.java) is the type of `com.emerchantpay.gateway.api.constants.Locales` used in the code.

Comment: `wpfRequest.setLanguage(new Locale(language));` - maybe with a check on language being in all locales.

Comment: Whats not working for you here? What is `wpfRequest` and `com.emerchantpay.gateway.api.constants.Locales`?

Comment: @nullpointer everything is working. How I can shrink the code?

Comment: You need to share what is `com.emerchantpay.gateway.api.constants.Locales` and why does it even exists and is the type of `language` in `wpfRequest` a `String`?

Comment: @nullpointer sure: https://github.com/GenesisGateway/genesis_java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/emerchantpay/gateway/api/constants/Locales.java

Answer (score 0):

Since the Locale you are using is `java.util.Locale` itself. You can simply set the language as:

```
wpfRequest.setLanguage(requestLocale);
```

and there is no need for the `if` conditions there.

---

Side note: You should think of renaming the attributes, since langauge as a name for storing `Locale` is misleading.

Also, you can probably get rid of your `com.emerchantpay.gateway.api.constants.Locales` model altogether as its redundant if you take a look at the `Locale` class implementation with the JDK, which internally something like this -

```
public static final Locale ENGLISH = createConstant("en", "");
```

Comment: I get incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Locale

Comment: @PeterPenzov ya update the solution, since I notied that your language attribute is of type `Locale`.